# VS 2008 project "incompatible" when converted to VS 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, mfc

I've got an MFC Application project under Visual Studio 2008 on XP (though I think it was started under an earlier version). When I asked to open it on a machine with VS 2012 on Windows 8.1 it translated the .vcproj to a .vcxproj and updated the .sln file but when I try to open it I just get a message "this project is incompatible with the current edition of Visual Studio". I can't find any kind of log file with any more info. The "new project" wizard only offers Windows Store apps and DLLs.

Comment: Are you running an Express Edition of Visual Studio 2012?

Comment: John did my answer end up solving your problem?

Comment: @Idos: Well, it's different; now it says (load failed) and "The project requires user input. Reload the project for more information". Re-opening it gets the same message, and menu item Project | Rescan Solution doesn't do anything either.

Changing the Version in the .sln file just makes it repeat the generation of the .vcxproj from the .vcproj.

There are 7 lines beginning "Import Project" in the .vcxproj (none in the .vcproj); I replaced the one that ended with ".targets".

Comment: @IInspectable: Thanks for the hint, I've dug around on the Microsoft site and found that it doesn't support MFC -- why didn't it say that was what was wrong? I'm now downloading VS Community 2015, we'll see what that does.

Comment: @IInspectable: Yes, with VS Community 2015 I only got problems that had sensible error messages, and it now compiles and runs. I'm new here, but I think you need to resubmit your comment as an Answer so I can click Accept and give you Brownie points?

Comment: @JohnGrant: Since you have all the background information it would be more appropriate for you to [answer your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 1):

OK, it turns out that by just following the most obvious "download" link on the Microsoft site I'd got an "express" version that doesn't support MFC (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hs24szh9%28v=vs.140%29.aspx).

They really should give an error message that gives some clue as to what the problem is, though.